# How should i implement polymorphic references of type object in project?

Tags: java

The following is program that I have been working upon and have got stuck.

The arrayList must take the objects as Dog

```
ArrayList<Dog> myDogArryList=new ArrayList<Dog>();
Dog aDog=new Dog();
myDogArrayList.add(aDog);
Dog d=myDogArrayList.get(0);
```

Now if I want a Generics arrayList to take objects of all kinds:
I can use "object" type in array list for the generics.
Please guide with a program implementation or give any other sample working code from Where I can have a clear understanding.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Object> myDogArrayList=new ArrayList<Object>();
Dog aDog=new Dog();
myDogArrayList.add(aDog);//works sice Object is an ancestor of all classes 
//it return the type as Object , so need to cast it 
Dog d=(Dog)myDogArrayList.get(0)
```

;

Please **Note**: Suppose you have superclass of Dog ,say `Animal` you may consider making the ArrayList as `ArrayList<Animal>` , It is not Advisable to make `ArrayList<Object>` type .

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList itself will take any kind of Object, and you can mix them if you wan't?

But If you wan't some type safety you will likely wan't to do something like this:

```
class Dog extends Animals {
}

class Cat extends Animals {
}

List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Dog());
animals.add(new Cat());
```